# Trello – assignment to others

Tags: trello

I'd like to keep track within Trello of things I've asked others to do, including clients, partners, etc. I can't really ask them to create a login in Trello just to help me. So is there a way to identify that this card is not for me to do something but actually for someone else, other than just putting their name in the title obviously ? Ideally, I'd like to be able to add them as "ghost member" or something like that.
By the way, it would be nice to have a suggestion board in Trello itself where users can suggest things.

Comment: +1 for "ghost members". Note that you can track, comment and vote on suggested features on the [Trello Development Board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c).

Comment: Is this a question about using Trello or a support request?

Comment: @Rebecca, this is an enhancement request really

Comment: The general community here cannot help with requests to the Trello team.  See the [Trello tag wiki](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/trello/info) for information on how to contact them.