# Can I create "fake" users with Trello?

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trello – assignment to others](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19329/trello-assignment-to-others)

I am using Trello as a management tool to visually organize, assign and display cases / what people are working on etc. I was wondering if I could create "fake" users that correspond to my employees.

I would like to assign users to cases in an environment that they don't necessarily know about / see. There is no need for my actual employees to see the board as they track their issues / time with FogBugz and I don't want them to have to maintain two systems, but I would still like to use it to organize them. This functionality would probably be better once undo/delete was implemented...

Is such a thing possible?